# Python, Selenium, Chromedriver & TOR - website not rendering correctly

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, tor

I managed to get Python Selenium work with TOR in order to anon IP address, using the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
torexe = os.popen(r'.\tor\tor.exe')
PROXY = "socks5://localhost:9050" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 1,
         "javascript.enabled": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'../../ChromeDriver.LENOVO/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://asdfiles.com")
```

It is slow but that's ok: it is expected. And it works fine: with icanhazip.com I can check that I am browsing with another IP. **HOWEVER**, when I try to load https://asdfiles.com/ the page is not rendering correctly, as the screenshot below:

[image]

**WHEN I LOAD IN TOR BROWSER, it renders correctly:**

[image]

The problem is that there is a buttom a need to click using selenium, and when I do that nothing happens. I tried to inspect the code and found nothing. Tried to enable javascript on chromedriver and it did not work also.

**Any suggestions how to tacke this?**

I am running Python 3.8.8 on Windows 10;
When I run tor.exe it says: Tor 0.3.2.10 running on Windows 8 with Libevent 2.0.22-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2n, Zlib 1.2.8, Liblzma N/A, and Libzstd N/A;
Chome 96.0.4664.45 (Versão oficial) 64 bits

Cheers!

Comment: maybe first check in `DevTools`, tab `Network` which files it has problem to load. Maybe it has problem with some IP address.

Comment: @furas I see something very strange: a lot of read files in networks. As an example, one of the css styles, code 403 (forbiden). any ideas?
Request URL: https://static.asdfiles.com/themes/flow/frontend_assets/css/stylesheet.css
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:9050
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin